# Why I am able to assign constant shared_ptr to non constant shared_ptr in C++?

Tags: c++, constants

I thought I can't assign a constant `shared_ptr` to a non-constant `shared_ptr`. But surprisingly I am able to assign as below and it is working fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const std::shared_ptr<const string> a = std::make_shared<const string>("Hello world");

    std::shared_ptr<const string> b = a;
    cout << "a count " << a.use_count() << ", b count " << b.use_count() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`.use_count()` is getting printed as 2. Can any one please help me to understand how I am able to do it?

Comment: What could happen that isn't intended? Does this break const-correctness anywhere?

Comment: you not assigned const pointer to not const pointer. you copy object data. pointers was inside *shared_ptr* object

Comment: and exist [`shared_ptr& operator=( const shared_ptr& r )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator=) and [`shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) which explicit allow `b = a;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The situation in your code is exactly the same as here:

```
const int a = 5;
int b = a;
std::cout << "a=" << a ", b=" << b << std::endl; // a=5, b=5
b = 10;
std::cout << "a=" << a ", b=" << b << std::endl; //a=5, b=10
```

Not particularly surprising, right? I had `const int`, and I used it to initialize non-const `int`. The value from `a` got copied into `b` and `a` wasn't modified at all.

Same occurs with `const std::shared_ptr`. Copy-constructing another object is not modifying the original object.

`use_count` can be changed, because it's not a member of `std::shared_ptr` class. `std::shared_ptr` requires two memory blocks allocated on the heap - a control block and actual object block.
Every `std::shared_ptr` instance only stores a pointer to the control block and to the actual object. The control block stores use count (number of `std::shared_ptr`s that hold the pointer to it).

When you copy `std::shared_ptr`, it increments the use count in control block and gets the same two pointers. When `std::shared_ptr` dies, it decrements use count (and deletes both blocks if use count reaches 0).

So, to sum up: use count is not a member of `std::shared_ptr`, and as such it can change even for `const std::shared_ptr` (otherwise `const std::shared_ptr` would be quite useless).

Comment: You may want to point out how the `use_count` of the original object was modified since the pointer is `const`.

Comment: By the same logic why I am not able to assign const char * to char *?

Comment: @kadina Because a `const char *` is not the same thing as a `const shared_ptr<T>`.  In `const char *` the `const` applies to the `char`, not the `*`.For the same thing you need a `char * const`, and that **can** be assigned to a `char *`.

Comment: really more near example (very primitive) - https://godbolt.org/z/SHe68r

Comment: @kadina because analog to `const char *` is `std::shared_ptr<const char>` not `const std::shared_ptr<char>`

Answer (score 7):

The `string` that `a` and `b` are *pointing* at is still `const` in both cases, but the pointer `b` isn't, so you could change what `b` is pointing at:

```
std::shared_ptr<const string> b = a;
b = std::make_shared<const string>("New string");
```

But you can't change what `a` is pointing at (since `a` is `const`):

```
a = std::make_shared<const string>("Won't compile");
```

Similarly:

```
const char* const a = "Hello world";
const char* b = a;

const char* c = "Something else";
b = c;    // the pointer "b" is not const and can be changed
// a = c; // won't compile since the pointer "a" itself is const
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    const auto a = std::make_shared<const std::string>("Hello world");

    auto b = a;
    std::cout << "a count " << a.use_count() << ", b count " << b.use_count() << "\n";
}
```

Types allowing copy-construction from a mutable object, but not from a constant one, are very rare and all user-defined. Mostly, they pre-date move-semantics, and thus C++11.
`std::shared_ptr`, introduced with C++11, is not such an exception. Why should it?